# Compiler assumptions about relative locations from memory objects

Tags: gcc, compilation, clang, compiler-optimization

I wonder what assumptions compilers make about the relative locations of memory objects.

For example if we allocate two stack variables of size 1 byte each, right after another and initialize them both with zero, can a compiler optimize this case by only emitting one single instruction that overwrites both bytes in memory with zeros, because the compiler knows the relative position of both variables?

I am interested specifically in the more well known compilers like gcc, g++, clang, the Windows C/C++ compiler etc.

Comment: Can it? Yes of course. Will it? Try and see.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler *can* optimize multiple assignments into one.

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
```

might become something like

```
*(short*)&a = 0;
```

The subtle part is "if we allocate two stack variables of size 1 byte each, right after another" since you cannot really do that. A compiler can shuffle stack positions around at will. Also, simply declaring variables will not necessarily mean any stack allocation. Variables might just be in registers. In C you would have to use `alloca` and even that does not provide "right after another".

Even more general, the C standard does not allow you to compare the memory positions of different objects. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: If the C standard defines this as undefined behaviour, does, e.g. gcc, comply with the standard and does not use optimizations like this?

Comment: @user2600312 it's undefined behaviour if *you* use code like that. The compiler can do it if it knows it's going to work, which it can know because it's compiling for a specific target in a specific way - it can *make* it work.